# Optimise which.max along multiple dimensions of an array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have some code with a 4 dimensional array, and I need to apply which.max across multiple dimensions. Its quite slow, I'd like to find ways to speed it up.

Example:

```
library(microbenchmark)

array4d <- array( runif(5*500*50*5 ,-1,0),
                  dim = c(5, 500, 50, 5) )

microbenchmark(
    max_idx <- apply(array4d, c(1,2,3), which.max )
    )
```

Any tips appreciated, thanks!

Edit:
I've managed to make it marginally faster (though ugly) by directly coding it out in for loops - but I'm hoping someone out there has better ideas!

```
method1 <- function(z) {
    apply(z, c(1,2,3), which.max)
}
method2 <- function(z){
    result <- array( , dim = dim(z)[1:3] )
    for(i in 1:dim(z)[1]){
        for(j in 1:dim(z)[2]){
            for(k in 1:dim(z)[3]){
                result[i, j, k] <- which.max(z[i,j,k,])
            }
        }
    }
    return(result)
}

microbenchmark(
result1 <- method1(array4d),
result2 <- method2(array4d))

> microbenchmark(
+     result1 <- method1(array4d),
+     result2 <- method2(array4d)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 result1 <- method1(array4d) 111.9061 140.1400 165.2441 155.6773 170.3967 384.6425   100   b
 result2 <- method2(array4d) 113.4572 123.2429 136.8583 130.8505 141.9620 215.0968   100  a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to more methods. One using R the other tuning code from @Allan-Cameron:

```
method4 <- function(z){
  result <- array(integer(1) , dim = head(dim(z), -1))
  n <- prod(head(dim(z), -1))
  j <- seq_len(tail(dim(z),1)) * n - n
  for(i in seq_len(n)) result[i] <- which.max(z[i+j])
  result}
```

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
NumericVector method5(const NumericVector &input){
  std::vector<int> dims = input.attr(\"dim\");
  int last_dim = dims.back();
  int diff = input.size()/last_dim;
  std::vector<int> result(diff);
  dims.pop_back();
  
  for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
  {
    double max_val = input[i];
    int max_ind = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < last_dim; ++j)
    {
      if(input[i+j*diff] > max_val) {
        max_val = input[i+j*diff];
        max_ind = j;
      }
    }
    result[i] = max_ind + 1;
  }
  
  NumericVector arr = wrap(result);
  arr.attr(\"dim\") = dims;
  return arr ;
}"
)
```

Timings:

```
set.seed(42)
array4d <- array(runif(5*500*50*5, -1, 0), dim = c(5, 500, 50, 5))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  check = "equal", control=list(order="block")
, method1(array4d)         #Using code from Question
, method2(array4d)         #Using code from Question
, apply_which_max(array4d) #Using code from Allan Cameron
, method4(array4d)
, method5(array4d)
)
#Unit: microseconds
#                     expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval  cld
#         method1(array4d) 200857.804 228567.850 266815.6275 254530.3050 294578.1125 423838.879   100    d
#         method2(array4d) 144767.680 149616.981 162367.6556 150688.1860 182290.4980 315650.052   100   c 
# apply_which_max(array4d)   3131.482   3153.712   3346.1025   3175.9445   3206.2220   5922.866   100 a   
#         method4(array4d)  58618.275  60777.584  62334.8258  61198.1815  61702.2170 165254.042   100  b  
#         method5(array4d)    894.823    902.862    972.2953    911.9845    927.0885   2643.957   100 a
```

For random select, instead of first match:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
NumericVector method6(const NumericVector &input){
  std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
  std::vector<int> dims = input.attr(\"dim\");
  int last_dim = dims.back();
  int diff = input.size()/last_dim;
  std::vector<int> result(diff);
  dims.pop_back();
  
  for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
  {
    double max_val = input[i];
    std::vector<int> max_ind = {0};
    for(int j = 1; j < last_dim; ++j)
    {
      if(input[i+j*diff] > max_val) {
        max_val = input[i+j*diff];
        max_ind.clear();
        max_ind.push_back(j);
      } else if(input[i+j*diff] == max_val) max_ind.push_back(j);
    }
    result[i] = max_ind[std::rand() % max_ind.size()] + 1;
  }
  
  NumericVector arr = wrap(result);
  arr.attr(\"dim\") = dims;
  return arr ;
}"
)
```

Comment: Very nice @GKi . Why do you think there's such a speed improvement in your c++ code compared to mine?

Comment: @AllanCameron The main improvement comes from not using `input.size()` in the loop.

Comment: Wow impressive speedboosts! For now I think I'm going to stick with the R option and keep C++ for later. At some point I plan to replace various parts of my code with C++ and since I must learn as I do makes sense to do it all together when I'm ready. But for now I'll have to figure out how that R code works  One question - is ```seq_len(n)``` faster than ```1:n``` ?

Comment: @user2498193 There shouldn't be much difference in speed between `seq_len(n)` and `1:n` but `seq_len` gives me the right sequence also for the in case when `n=0`.

Comment: FYI I think there's a small bug in ur R code implementation - in the line defining j, used ```array4d``` instead of ```z```

Comment: Thanks both @AllanCameron & @GKi - my overall program is about 15% faster now. I have more similar optimisations to do, but I'll will try an apply what I'm learning here. If I can't figure things out I may be back  Anyhow, plenty to work on before the 4D ```aperm``` command becomes the blocking point 

Comment: @GKi - sorry i'm not very strong in c++ how does this deal with ties in current form? I think it takes the first at max_val if there are ties right? Is it possible to modify it to do random ties?

Comment: @user2498193 which.max also takes the first max. Then you change the part around `input[i+j*diff] > max_val` you can include random selection.

Comment: Yep I'm know ```which.max``` takes first max, but the function ```nnet::which.is.max``` can be dropped in instead to give random sampling. Thanks for the direction - not sure i'm up to it but  will try

Comment: @user2498193 When you change `if(input[i+j*diff] > max_val) {` to `if(input[i+j*diff] > max_val || (input[j] == max_val && std::rand() % 2 == 0)) {` it should randomly select. When you add `std::srand(std::time(nullptr));` in the beginning also the seed should be randomly.

Comment: @GKi thanks for suggestion. I had thought about such an approach but the problem is samples won't be random due to conditional probability it introduces. Imagine there are 5 equal maxes - the fifth one could only be selected if all the previous ones are not, whereas the first one has 5 potential chances to be selected. Perhaps if I change max_ind to a vector, accrue matches, then select 1 from the vector ? OR is max_ind used for indexing the loop also?

Comment: @user2498193 I added some code which stores all hits and selects then one of them. Hope this is now random.

Comment: @GKi this all works great thanks as ```Rcpp::cppFunction``` calls inline, but I'm trying to put in stnadalone files and on compilation I'm getting error with ```input.attr(\"dim\")```. Do I need to remove these escapes or something?

Comment: Yes removing those escapes seems to have fixed it. I have lots to learn here!

Answer (score 3):

When you want to add a bit of speed in R and you have exhausted the simple gains using native vectorization, you should think `Rcpp`.

Here's an implementation of your algorithm using C++ wrapped in a call to `Rcpp:cppFunction`:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("
NumericVector apply_which_max(NumericVector input){
  std::vector<int> dims = input.attr(\"dim\");
  int last_dim = dims.back();
  int diff = input.size()/last_dim;
  std::vector<int> result(diff);
  dims.pop_back();
  
  for(int i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
  {
    double max_val = input[i];
    int max_ind = i;
    for(int j = i; j < input.size(); j += diff)
    {
      if(input[j] > max_val) {
        max_val = input[j];
        max_ind = j;
      }
    }
    result[i] = max_ind / diff + 1;
  }
  
  NumericVector arr = wrap(result);
  arr.attr(\"dim\") = dims;
  return arr ;
}"
)
```

We better show that it has the same output:

```
max_idx1 <- apply(array4d, c(1 ,2, 3), which.max)
max_idx2 <- apply_which_max(array4d)

all(max_idx1 == max_idx2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

But is it faster?

Using the benchmarks (on my slow machine), we get:

```
microbenchmark(apply(array4d, c(1 ,2, 3), which.max))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq
#>  apply(array4d, c(1, 2, 3), which.max) 243.2283 276.5381 342.5796 330.0815 403.8358
#>       max neval
#>  543.8325   100

microbenchmark(apply_which_max(array4d))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                      expr    min     lq     mean median     uq    max neval
#>  apply_which_max(array4d) 3.1761 3.2725 3.713377  3.342 3.4088 12.962   100
```

That is, not just faster, but around 100 times faster.

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron. That's an impressive speedboost. Indeed I was aware of this option, but I'm not too confident when it comes to cpp, so had avoided it hoping there were gains in R to be had. May I ask, in your C code I see only 2 for loops - how are you avoiding the third for loop ? And does this solution scale to arbitrary size (within the 4dimenions that is).

Comment: @user2498193 it takes advantage of the fact that in R an array is actually stored internally as a vector with a `dim` attribute. The elements are therefore stored in such a way that you can use one-dimensional vector indexing to pick out the equivalent entries in each "layer" of the final dimension. In an array with dimensions a x b x c x d, the first a x b x c elements will be the first layer, the second a x b x c elements the second layer, and so on. The two loops are therefore iterating through layers and within layers respectively.

Comment: This should scale well to arbitrary sizes and should work for any number of dimensions greater than 1. I think it's O(n). The only obvious limitation is that it only works across the final dimension of an array, so you can't do the equivalent of `apply(array4d, c(2, 3, 4), which.max)` without first transposing the array. To be honest, thinking about transposing a 4d array makes my head hurt, so I haven't implemented that here.

Comment: ha yeah the 4D arrays are kind of a nightmare to work with  Thanks very much for the solution and explanations!